# c# cannot use memory stream to convert byte array to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, console, memorystream

I have been looking for days now and all the current answers on how to convert a byte[] filled with imageData leads me back to this piece of code:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byte[])) 
{
  Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

something like this at least (I have made so many versions of it by now.. I don't remember the original) 
but no matter how I use it, I always get a 'parameter invalid' for the parameter when I try to put the stream in my bitmap.

here is how I´m saving it at the moment:

```
private static byte[] ConvertToByteArr(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        byte[] result;            
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);            
        result = stream.ToArray();

        return result;
    }
```

and calling it when I save my dictionary to a .txt file

this is how I´m trying to read it again.

```
 TextReader reader = new StreamReader(trainingPath + "\\" + filename + ".txt");
        Dictionary<string, string> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        String line;
        String[] parts;

        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            parts = line.Split('=');

            string key = parts[0];
            string value = parts[1];
            tempDict.Add(key, value);

            Console.WriteLine("added " + key + " to temp Dict");

            byte[] byteArr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempDict[key]);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr);

            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));

            parts[0] = null;
            parts[1] = null;

        }
```

everything works until the Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Image.Fromstream(ms)) line.

Comment: `I always get a 'parameter invalid'` What **exact** exception is thrown? By which line of code?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `tempDict[key]` when the exception occurs?

Comment: Dont be converting binary data to strings and back, this is a one way street to not working

Comment: mjwills I get a 'System.ArgumentException' 
the value of tempDict[key] is a byte array with data from a bitmap I convertet so that I could save a lot of data into categorized .txt files.

Comment: saruman- I only do this because I have too much data. 

I am working on a machine learning project and I need to feed a lot of data into it. but these are saved as dictionaries <string, bitmap> to make sure I have the right information. 
I thought that saving it to a .txt file would take less processing power from the computer than saving and searching through a database.

Answer (score 0):

Using Encoding.GetBytes() and Encoding.GetString() is not recommended.
There is a case that the above mutual conversion does not go well.
(Like you experienced)

I would recommend to use hexademical string.
You can convert byte array to string (Hexademical) as follows:

```
byte[] byteArr = ConvertToByteArr(bitmap);
string str = BitConverter.ToString(byteArr).Replace("-", "");
```

Also, you can convert the string (Described above) to byte array as follows:

```
private byte[] HexaToBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[str.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = str.Substring(i * 2, 2);
        byteArr[i] = Convert.ToByte(s, 16);
    }
    return byteArr;
}
```

Comment: so, I´ve tried to implement this, but I get an error when it hits the 

byte[i] = Convert.ToByte(s, 16);

it casts a 'System.FormatException

Comment: Or use base64 along with `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` and `Convert.FromBase64String(string)` easier than rolling your own hex converter and will take up less written bytes

Comment: @Tanya Sorry for late reply... How did you get the "str" (string) parameter for the **HexaToBytes** method? The string must be created from the byte array which was returned from the "ConvertToByteArr" method you defined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply :) I have solved this problem in a whole different manor, but I am not sure how to close this thread. 
I found that no matter how long I tried to fix it with this method it always ended corrupt

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading from the text file make sure that encoding is being used.
I tried a sample code where I saved bitmap as byte[] into a text file using the same method mentioned(ConvertToByteArr). 
I got the same error when I tried to create a bitmap object from the memorystream read from streamreader of that saved text file.

But when I used ASCII encoding it worked fine.

TextReader reader = new StreamReader(textfile, Encoding.ASCII, true);